# Is there a way for NSAttributedString to control the way of stroke?

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, stroke

I know there is a `NSStrokeWidthAttributeName` property can set stroke width.

However, is there a way to control whether to stoke inside or outside or center? I found the lib [THLabel](https://github.com/MuscleRumble/THLabel) can set it. But is there a official way to do this?

Comment: Did you try with positive or negative values?

Comment: @Larme Yes, I tried. But neither positive nor negative can give the text effect I want.